# Deploy from Git to Azure: Running oryx build step is stopped without a any errors on log

Tags: azure, github, .net-core

I am trying to auto deploy github's repository (.net-core 3.1) to azure AppService slot, when I try to deploy it always ends up with status Failed.

The logs does not tell nothing:

```
{
    "id": "*****",
    "status": 3,
    "status_text": "",
    "author_email": "****",
    "author": "****",
    "deployer": "GitHub",
    "message": "*****",
    "progress": "",
    "received_time": "2020-10-14T08:27:43.3948241Z",
    "start_time": "2020-10-14T08:27:43.4878155Z",
    "end_time": "2020-10-14T08:28:43.9140325Z",
    "last_success_end_time": null,
    "complete": true,
    "active": false,
    "is_temp": false,
    "is_readonly": false,
    "url": "https://*****.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/*****",
    "log_url": "https://*****.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/*****/log",
    "site_name": "*****"
},
```

This is the `log_url`:

```
[
    {
        "log_time": "2020-10-14T08:27:43.4458716Z",
        "id": "****",
        "message": "Updating submodules.",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2020-10-14T08:27:43.4778886Z",
        "id": "****",
        "message": "Preparing deployment for commit id '****'.",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2020-10-14T08:27:43.5716472Z",
        "id": "****",
        "message": "Repository path is /home/site/repository",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2020-10-14T08:27:43.5945004Z",
        "id": "****",
        "message": "Running oryx build...",
        "type": 2,
        "details_url": "https://****.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/****/log/****"
    }
]
```

Here is the `details_url`:

```
Command: oryx build /home/site/repository -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform dotnet --platform-version 3.1 -i /tmp/8d870249a6c09c6 --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20200805.1, Commit: ****, ReleaseTagName: 20200805.1

Build Operation ID: |***=.***_
Repository Commit : ****

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
dotnet: 3.1.6

Using intermediate directory '/tmp/***'.

Copying files to the intermediate directory...
Done in 3 sec(s).

Source directory : /tmp/****
Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot


Using .NET Core SDK Version: 3.1.302
Determining projects to restore...

*******

Publishing to directory /home/site/wwwroot...

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.

****

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.

Done in 57 sec(s).
\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /home/site/repository -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform dotnet --platform-version 3.1 -i /tmp/***** --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log
```

[image]

I can't see any errors in the deploy process, all of the project dependencies are restored successfully and I can not see any errors on log.

Any idea why is the deploy process is being terminated so the step `Running post deployment command(s)...` is not being triggered? or any idea how to dig further the logs for the reason?

There is nothing wrong with the project code because when I deploy the project via manual FTP everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by deleting the app service slot, and create a new one from scratch.